# How to insert a prop into a string to use as an iframe call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, twitch

I am trying to embed twitch streams in a react app and am struggling how to figure out how to get props to work in an iFrame call.

In my app.js I have a call such as,

```
<Stream name="streamname" />
```

In stream.js I have,

```
<iframe
   src={"https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=" + { ... this.props } + "&parent=localhost"}
   height="540"
   width="960"
   allowFullScreen={false}
    frameBorder="0" >
</iframe>
```

when src is set to `"https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=channelname&parent=localhost"` everything works fine as expected. Its just when I try to add the props is when things get messed up.

For example the embedded link that is created is `https://www.twitch.tv/[object%20Object]/`

Answer (score 0):

Colin your question is not much clear what you wanna achieve, please
you can use template literals it is better way to combine string and variables
src={

```
`https://player.twitch.tv/?channel= ${ this.props.name }&parent=localhost`
```

}
what is coming in **this.props** that you are spreading

Comment: above it I stated I am calling the stream component that has the prop `name=streamname`. The iframe is being returned from a react component called Stream

Comment: do it like that add back tick ` 
I am trying to add but it's removing 
src={```https://player.twitch.tv/?channel= ${ this.props.name }&parent=localhost```}

Comment: you can check the above answer I updated added back tick that was missing before

Comment: can you share code and console.log(this.props) and send screenshot please

Comment: don't spread {...this.props} just simply do it like that {this.props.name}